# How to navigate to external url in react-flux architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
class Chatbox extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };

}
componentDidMount() {

}
render() {
return (
        <div className="content_block"> 
            <Link to='/chatbox'></Link>
         </div>
    )
}
}
export default Chatbox;
```

I am rendering the chatbox component in that render area I need to run the other application url.

I am using below route but It is redirecting to that location instead of rendering in the chatbox render area.

```
<Route path='/chatbox' component={() => window.location = 'http://localhost:5000/chat'}/>
```

How to navigate the "http://localhost:5000/chat" url in the component render area.

Answer (score 1):

You may use iframe to render external site inside yours.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="content_block"> 
         <iframe src="http://localhost:5000/chat" width="640" height="480" align="left">Not supported</iframe>
     </div>
  );
}
```